# Java compile error overriding generic method with generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

```
import java.util.Collection;

public abstract class A {

    public class R<T> { }

    public abstract <X> R<X> get1();

    public abstract <X> R<X> get2(Collection<String> p);

    public abstract <X> R<X> get3(Collection<Integer> p);

    public class B extends A {

        @Override
        public R<Object> get1() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public R<Object> get2(Collection<String> p) {
            return null;
        }   

        @Override
        public <Object> R<Object> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `get1` method works fine but there is a compile error for `get2`:

- > The method get2(Collection) of type A.B must override or implement a supertype method

This error only arises with parameters with generics. `get3` compiles but there is of course a warning:

- > The type parameter Object is hiding the type Object

Clearly there are other ways to solve this but in my understanding this should be a legal overriding and my question is more why there is this compile error. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Sorry, my example was not clear enough. Therefore here is a new to react to some points of your answers.

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract class R<T> { }

    public abstract <X> R<X> get();

    public abstract <Y> R<Y> get2(Collection<String> p);

    public abstract <Z> R<Z> get3(Collection<Integer> p);

    public class B extends A {

        @Override
        public R<String> get() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public R<Double> get2(Collection<String> p) {
            return null;
        }   

        @Override
        public <V> R<V> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

- Same compile error as above for `get2`, and a obvious type safety warning for `get` which i would expect to get on `get2` as well.
- I want every method to has its own type, so a class type is not the solution.
- To use Object was a bad decision for this example but it was not my point and the type hiding problem for the old `get3` is clear as mentioned above.
- The problem lies within the signatures, as lexicore said. Therefore i will comment his answer.

Comment: I will check your updates later on and see what I can do. Beyond that: is this a theoretical question or are you trying to solve a real problem here?

Comment: It comes from a real problem but i already have different working solutions in mind. So it is more theoretical.

Comment: Reason why I am asking is that the design of the base interface looks suspicious. For the real problem I would carefully evaluate if you really need and want these all these different generics in one class.

Comment: Normally this is way more complex and not in one class. My intention was only to provide a small reproducable example. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you replace `Collection<String>` with `String` the error goes away, so it seems to be caused by the parameter type being generic. Might be a bug, but Oracle javac and ECJ have the same behavior so it's more likely due to some arcane rule for generic signature resolution in the java language spec.

Comment: Seems like you don't need that advice, as you got all things right regarding the content of your question then :-)

Comment: Yes, as already stated above the error only arises with generic parameters.

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8203191

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As lexicore already said, your answer does not explain why 'B.get2' does not override 'A.get2'. And as this is my real question, in my opinion it is not solved, even when i am still hoping that the problem is on my side. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
public <Object> R<Object> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
```

is probably **not** what you meant.

You are introducing another *type variable*, called `Object` here.

Compare that to:

```
public R<Object> get2(Collection<String> p) {
```

In other words: `get2()`uses java.lang.Object. `get3()` uses a **generic** type that is unfortunately named `Object`. You could as well write

```
public <NONSENSE> R<NONSENSE> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
```

And finally: `get2()` isn't what you would be doing either. See the excellent answer from Michael for that part.

Comment: Correct, but this is only a partial answer. Fixing that will not solve any compiler warnings. Using `Object` as a type parameter identifier will compile quite happily, though it somewhat contradicts OP's intentions.

Comment: @Michael Correct; I added a "delegation" to your answer for that!

Comment: I don't understand why `B.get` overrides `A.get` but `B.get2` does not override `A.get2`. `B.get2` has the same signature as `A.get2`. JLS: [Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) Which of these criteria pass for `get` but not for `get2`?

Comment: @lexicore your  "_`B.get2` has the same signature as `A.get2`_" comment is incorrect. I explain why [*in my answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62503250/4465539).

Answer (score 2):

[As GhostCat already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293570/1898563), `Object` in `get3` is actually a type variable. That is, funnily enough, what you should have used, but with a confusing name.

To fix your inner class, you must re-declare the generic type parameters again for all 3 methods:

```
public class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public <X> R<X> get1() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> R<X> get2(Collection<String> p) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> R<X> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, all that repetition of `<X>` suggests you should move the generic type parameter to the class `A`. Here's the way I would implement this:

```
abstract class A<X>
{
    public class R<T> { }

    public abstract R<X> get1();

    public abstract R<X> get2(Collection<String> p);

    public abstract R<X> get3(Collection<Integer> p);

    public class B extends A<X>
    {
        @Override
        public R<X> get1() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public R<X> get2(Collection<String> p) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public R<X> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If `B` pertains to all `Object`s (it's not clear from your example), you could replace the inner class above with:

```
public class B extends A<Object>
{
    @Override
    public R<Object> get1() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public R<Object> get2(Collection<String> p) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public R<Object> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why `B.get2` does not override `A.get2`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why *`B.get2()`* does not override *`A.get2()`* is because the two don't have ***the same type parameters*** [*according to the JLS*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4-300)...

> ...*Two methods or constructors *`M1`* and *`M2`* have the same type parameters if both of the following are true:*...
>
> 1. *`M1`* *and* *`M2`* *have same number of type parameters (possibly zero).*
> 2. *Where `A1, ..., An` are the type parameters of `M` and `B1, ..., Bn` are the type parameters of `N`, let `θ=[B1:=A1, ..., Bn:=An]`. Then, for all `i (1 ≤ i ≤ n)`, the bound of `Ai` is the same type as `θ` applied to the bound of `Bi`.*

*`A.get2()`* has the *`public abstract <X>`* [*type parameter section*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4-110). But the `R<Double>` in  *`public R<Double> B.get2()`*  is not a ***type parameter*** in that particular context. In that context,  `Double` is a ***type argument*** in an ***invocation*** (*an instantiation*) of the same-named generic method in *`A`*.

In order to have a JLS-legal override situation, two methods ***MUST*** be [*what the JLS calls **override-equivalent***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-130)...

> ...*Two method signatures *`M1`* and *`M2`* are override-equivalent iff either *`M1`* is a subsignature of *`M2`*  or *`M2`*  is a subsignature of *`M1`**...

Two methods cannot be override-equivalent unless one of the two is a [***subsignature***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-120) of the other...

> ...
>
> *The signature of a method *`M1`* is a subsignature of the signature of a method *`M2`*  if either:*...
>
> 1. **`M2`*  has the same signature as *`M1`*, or*
> 2. *the signature of *`M1`* is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of *`M2`* .*
>
> ...

Two methods cannot be subsignatures of each other unless they have the same signature...

> ...*Two methods have the **same signature** if they have the same name and argument types*...

Your two methods don't have the same signature because they don't meet *[**the same argument types** condition of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-110)*...

> ...
>
> *Two method or constructor declarations `M` and `N` have the same argument types if all of the following conditions hold:*
>
> 1. *They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)*
> 2. *They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)*
> 3. *Let *`A1 , ..., An`* be the type parameters of `M` and let *`B1, ..., Bn`* be the type parameters of `N`. After renaming each occurrence of a *`Bi`* in `N`'s type to *`Ai`*, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the same, and the formal parameter types of `M` and `N` are the same.*
>
> ...

So, for *`B.get2()`* to compile — *and for `B.get()` to be 100% type safe* — then you need to change the methods to be override-equivalent.

The simplest way to do that is to make them have the same number of type parameters as the ones in *`A`* that they override...

```
import java.util.Collection;

public abstract class A {

    public abstract class R<T> {

    public abstract <X> R<X> get();

    public abstract <Y> R<Y> get2(Collection<String> p);

    public abstract <Z> R<Z> get3(Collection<Integer> p);

    public static class B extends A {

        @Override
        public <T> R<T> get() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <U> R<U> get2(Collection<String> p) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <V> R<V> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
public <X> R<X> get2(Collection<String> p){
...
public <X> R<X> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
...
```

Comment: This does not explain why `B.get2` does not override `A.get2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `X` generic type is not and `Object`, but rather something that **extends** `Object`, because it doesn't really make sense to replace an `Object` by `Object`. The valid prototype for your get2 method is this one:

```
// X or Y or any generic type or class
public <Y> R<Y> get2(Collection<String> p) {
    return null;
}
```

Same thing with your get3 method, you don't need generics to manipulate Objects, it should be something that extends `Object` instead

```
public <Y> R<Y> get3(Collection<Integer> p) {
     return null;
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why `B.get2` does not override `A.get2`.